# Computing Tor for $R=k[x,y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R=k[x,y]$ where $k$ is a field. I want to compute $\operatorname{Tor}_{i}^{R}(R/(y-x), R/(y^2 - x^3))$ for $i \ge 0$.

### My attempt is:

Since $\cdots \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow R \xrightarrow{\times(y-x)} R \rightarrow R/(y-x) \rightarrow 0$ is a projective resolution, $\operatorname{Tor}_{i}^{R}(R/(y-x), R/(y^2 - x^3)) =0 $ for $i \ge 2$.

$\operatorname{Tor}_{0}^{R}(R/(y-x), R/(y^2 - x^3)) \simeq R/(y-x, y^2 - x^3) \simeq k[t]/(t^2- t^3)$
since $R/(y-x) \simeq k[t]$ (by considering $k[x,y] \rightarrow k[t]$, $p(x,y) \mapsto p(t,t)$)

$\operatorname{Tor}_{1}^{R}(R/(y-x), R/(y^2 -x^3)) \simeq \{ m \in R/(y^2 -x^3) : (y-x)m=0 \ \textrm{mod } y^2 -x^3 \}$. (*I cannot go further from here.*)

---

This is somewhat an incomplete solution, but I'm not even sure whether the above argument is valid.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So $\text{Tor}_1$ (I won't write out the full notation) is the kernel of multiplication
by $y-x$ on $R/(y^2-x^3)$.

The ring $S=R/(y^2-x^3)$ is isomorphic to $k[t^2,t^3]$ (a subring of $k[t]$)
via $x\mapsto t^2$ and $y\mapsto t^3$. Multiplication by $y-x$ corresponds to
multiplication by $t^3-t^2$ on $S$. But $S$ is an integral domain, so the kernel
of this multiplication map is zero. Therefore $\text{Tor}_1=0$.

Comment: Oh, I see. I'd found that $R/(y^2 - x^3)$ is isomorphic to a subring of $k[t]$ but I didn't realize that it is isomorphic to $k[t^2, t^3]$. This is a little bit funny situation...  Well, are they ok for $i \neq 1$?